# Is there an alternative to rowCount in a query?

Tags: database, 8

In Drupal 8 we can not use the `rowCount` property anymore in case of a `select` statement. Is there an elegant alternative?

I can use a foreach, but when converting from Drupal 7 I would like to replace the `result->rowCount()` more elegantly.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [Drupal API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Statement.php/function/Statement%3A%3ArowCount/8.2.x), "in D8 rowCount() is the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed or throws \Drupal\Core\Database\RowCountException if the last executed statement was SELECT."

If you need to select count of rows you can use $query->addExpression('COUNT(*)');

```
   $query = \Drupal::database()->select('table', 't');
   $query->addExpression('COUNT(*)');
   $count = $query->execute()->fetchField();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')->fields('n', ['nid'])->execute();
$query->allowRowCount = TRUE;
$count = $query->rowCount();
```

Or:

```
$query = db_query('Select * from node');
$query->allowRowCount = TRUE;
$count = $query->rowCount();
```

**Note:** `db_select()` and `db_query()` are marked as deprecated, will be removed in Drupal 9.0.0. Instead, get a database connection injected into your service from the container and call `select()` or `query()` on it.

Comment: Are you sure this works for Drupal 8 db_select? I never got it to work. Александр Афанасьев worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Setting the `allowRowCount` property to TRUE is not a good way to solve this issue.

A better way to do this is to use  the built in [`countQuery`](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/database-api/dynamic-queries/count-queries):

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')->fields('n', ['nid']);
$num_rows = $query->countQuery()->execute()->fetchField();
```

Comment: It should be pointed out that the `if()` statement is not necessary, to count the number of selected rows.

Answer (score 0):

`rowCount()` is supported for DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statements performed with structured query builders only, since they would not be portable across database engines otherwise

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
$database = \Drupal::database();
$query = $database->select('node__field_node_url', 'nnu');
$query->addField('nnu', 'entity_id');
$query->condition('nnu.field_node_url_uri', "entity:node/" . $article->entity_id);
$results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
$count = count($results);
```